# intel ac 8260 bluetooth not working- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, bluetooth

I recently bought GC-wb867d-i wireless card for my new desktop. the wifi part works well, however the Bluetooth not woring. Following are some diagnostic info:

```
$ uname -a:

Linux chi-ubuntu 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ rfkill list all:

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no

$ lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm':

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:5744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2744 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04d9:1818 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.147778] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.262423] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    2.262431] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.262433] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.262434] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.262437] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.268137] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    2.268139] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    2.268140] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    2.268140] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    2.268141] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    2.268141] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    2.268158] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    2.268166] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    2.268167] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    2.338484] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.338496] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.338852] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.349462] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.367686]  snd_hda_codec mac80211 snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel(+) snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 snd_rawmidi lrw gf128mul iwlwifi glue_helper ablk_helper snd_seq cryptd snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211 snd serio_raw soundcore shpchp btusb btrtl mei_me mei hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth 8250_fintek intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss mac_hid acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio acpi_pad parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 mxm_wmi i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper e1000e psmouse syscopyarea sysfillrect ptp sysimgblt fb_sys_fops pps_core drm ahci libahci wmi video pinctrl_sunrisepoint pinctrl_intel i2c_hid hid fjes
[    3.623731] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.623733] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.623736] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.301904] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[   12.298070] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[   14.302048] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[   22.298394] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
```

it looks like the firmware for the card is not working. Does anyone have some idea?

By the way. I do have dual os install on this machine. win10 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The wifi and Bluetooth all work fine under win10.

Comment: the driver go back to normal after I buy another Bluetooth dongle and plug in, wired.